# React: Passing Props not working. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dataflow

as you may get from the title, passing props in react is not working. And i don´t get why.

**Main Ap Component**

```
import './App.css';
import Licence from './Licence';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Licence>
      test={"Test123"}
    </Licence>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**Other Component**

```
import React from 'react';


const Licence = (props) => {
    return (
    <div>
        <h1>name : {props.test}</h1>
    </div>
    )
}

export default Licence;
```

**Problem**
if i start the script and render the page, nothing is shown. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: when you do `test={"Test123"}` you are trying to pass an object. Please replace it with `test="Test123"`. It should resolve your issue.

Comment: @DhruviMakvana thanks for the answer. but same problem. nothing is shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Licence component looks good to me!

All you have to do is change up how you set it up on App. Props need to be passed on the tag, like this:

```
import './App.css';
import Licence from './Licence';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Licence test={"Test123"} />
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

update your App component:

````
```
<Licence
  test={"Test123"} />
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Pass like this

```
<Licence test={"Test123"} />
```

and access like this

```
const Licence = (props) => {
    return (
    <div>
        <h1>name : {props.test}</h1>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Another way

```
<Licence>
     Test123
 </Licence>
```

access like this

```
const Licence = (props) => {
    return (
    <div>
        <h1>name : {props.children}</h1>
    </div>
    )
}
```